# Faster way to read multiple csv to one data frame?

Tags: r

Is there anyway to speed up the following process in R?

```
theFiles <- list.files(path="./lca_rs75_summary_logs", full.names=TRUE, pattern="*.summarylog")

listOfDataFrames <- NULL
masterDataFrame <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(theFiles)) {
    tempDataFrame <- read.csv(theFiles[i], sep="\t", header=TRUE)
    #Dropping some unnecessary row
    toBeRemoved <- which(tempDataFrame$Name == "")
    tempDataFrame <- tempDataFrame[-toBeRemoved,]
    #Now stack the data frame on the master data frame
    masterDataFrame <- rbind(masterDataFrame, tempDataFrame)
}
```

Basically, I am reading multiple csv files in a directory. I want to combine all the csv files to one giant data frame by stacking the rows. The loop seems to longer to run as the masterDataFrame is growing in size. I am doing this on a linux cluster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Updated answer with `data.table::fread`.

```
require(data.table)
out = rbindlist(lapply(theFiles, function(file) {
         dt = fread(file)
         # further processing/filtering
      }))
```

`fread()` automatically detects header, file separator, column classes, doesn't convert strings to factor by default.. handles embedded quotes, is quite fast etc.. See `?fread` for more.

---

See history for old answers.

Comment: Thank you. rbindlist really speed things up!