# Combine multiple spreadsheet to one data frame in R

Tags: r

I take [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960246/faster-way-to-read-multiple-csv-to-one-data-frame) as reference

My original approach is:

```
DATA <- NULL
n <- length(list.files())

for (i in 1:n){
    wb <- loadWorkbook(list.files()[i])
    ws <- readWorksheet(wb, 
        sheet=getSheets(wb), header=TRUE, startRow=3, endCol=45)

    ws$Issue.Date <- as.Date(substr(ws$Issue.Date, 1, 10))   #i need to standardize the date format.
    ws$Flt.Date <- as.Date(substr(ws$Flt.Date, 1, 10))
    ws$Dnl.Date <- as.Date(substr(ws$Dnl.Date, 1, 10))
    ws$Ver.On <- as.Date(substr(ws$Ver.On, 1, 10))

    DATA <- rbind(DATA, ws)
}
```

While from the link, it mentioned do.call(rbind,...) so i tried:

```
> DATA2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(), function(x) {
+ wb <- loadWorkbook(x)
+ ws <- readWorksheet(wb,
+ sheet=getSheets(wb), header=TRUE, startRow=3, endCol=45)
+ ws$Issue.Date <- as.Date(substr(ws$Issue.Date, 1, 10))
+ ws$Flt.Date <- as.Date(substr(ws$Flt.Date, 1, 10))
+ ws$Dnl.Date <- as.Date(substr(ws$Dnl.Date, 1, 10))
+ ws$Ver.On <- as.Date(substr(ws$Ver.On, 1, 10))
+ }))
Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The function in the lapply statement should probably return ws instead of ws$Ver.On

Comment: Ohh thats mean i shd add ws before })). One more question is that how should compare above two approach running time? Thanks @shadow

Comment: To compare running times, I usually use the `microbenchmark` package.

Comment: which approach do you advice me to employ for combine spreadsheet?