# Combining longitudinal data in separate CSVs into one with year field?

Tags: r

I am very familiar with Excel but new to R. I have several years worth of data across multiple spreadsheets:

```
data1996.csv
data1997.csv
...
data2013.csv
```

Each csv is about 500,000 rows by 1700 columns.

I want to manipulate this data in D3 and plan to remove columns that are not essential to calculation. My goal is to create a slider with years that will create a corresponding visualization. I want to know what the easiest way is to aggregate these massive datasets. I suppose it could be done manually, but this would prove cumbersome and inefficient.

I am very new to R, but if there is another means to aggregate the data into a single CSV, that would work fine as well.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This has been discussed on this site before - try something like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960246/faster-way-to-read-multiple-csv-to-one-data-frame - basically - read all your `csv`s into a list, maybe dropping some on the way, then bind them together `rbindlist(lapply(filelist, fread, drop=c("vartodrop1","vartodrop2")))`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you